# Efficient Server side paging with EntityFramework Complex type

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I came accross with this link http://www.dbtutorials.com/display/linq-to-sql-paging-cs.aspx

which has e.g. of efficient server side paging in LINQ but i want to do same thing with Entity Framework but with Complex type is it possible ?

Comment: I don't see a reason why it won't be possible. If your select points to a complex type you can always add Skip and Take. Do you get any errors or other problems?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can still use `Skip` and `Take` with the LINQ to Entities provider, and these will be performed on the server. You should also look into [PagedList](https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList) which makes things even easier for you.